What commentaries were helpful when you read Manusmriti
I am interested in extensively studying Manu as well as its commentaries, but I need some advice. I would like to ask users, especially those who answer frequently on this site what commentary was most helpful to you. Please provide an archive link if plausible. Thank you.

A good commentary that elucidates much of Manu's words and how they were seen in Ancient India is the one by Medhatithi, translated by Ganganath Jha.
It can be found here and here.

To gain useful insights into the Manusmriti (Manu Smriti) and its commentaries one should study them. Learned authors such as the ancient Kulluka Bhatta, Medhatithi and Narayana wrote at length on this. In relation to historical context, Modern scholarly works like Patrick Olivelle, G. C. Tripathi's critical edition, and Chandra Chakranarayan's English translation provide different interpretations. They contain a host of historical editions that the users can get from Internet Archive, Google Books and JSTOR. By comparing various explanations given in commentaries by different commentators with an aim of getting wide range knowledge about these texts, it is important to note that there are many more perspectives than just one which may be limited to one individual perspective

Which one's did you personally read?
